# How do I import a .dat file as a matrix in Mathematica?

Tags: file, matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a .dat file consisting of a string of numbers 1 to 9 that looks like this:

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

How do I import the data into mathematica so that it has the form {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}} and I can generate my 3x3 matrix?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest:

```
  data=Partition[Import["<Name of data file>", "Table"],3];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReadList["file.dat", {Number, Number, Number}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

Can also be written:

```
ReadList["file.dat", Number ~Table~ {3}]
```