# Importing data into Mathematica in the form of a matrix

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica

I have a file which, when I import into Mathematica, looks like this: 
{{1,1,n1},{1,2,n2},{1,3,n3},{2,1,n4},{2,2,n5},{2,3,n6}} where n1...n6 are some numbers that I want to import as a matrix that looks like :

[image]

The first number in each block specifies the row and the second the column, but they are not a part of the matrix. Only the third number in each block is part of the matrix. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

If

```
data = {{1, 1, n1}, {1, 2, n2}, {1, 3, n3}, {2, 1, n4}, {2, 2, n5}, {2, 3, n6}};
```

you can simply do

```
mat = Partition[data[[All, 3]], 3, 3]
```

Comment: if the data is guaranteed to fill the matrix, but not ordered correctly, simply applying Sort[] should get you the correct order.  That may perform better than the sparsearray approach (or maybe not if you dont know the dimensions a priori.)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of interpretations of this question that I can think of.

If your data is in a regular format and you wish to read it in a memory efficient manner I recommend looking closely at `ReadList` and related functionality as I [already directed you toward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13746642/618728) and the `Partition` function that the other answer illustrates.

I shall instead focus on the idea that the data is not in an entirely regular form in that the given row and column indexes are necessary to describe the positions of the data in the array.  For that the most natural method is to use `SparseArray` at it accepts data in the form of position and value `Rule` pairs:

```
data = {{1, 1, n1}, {1, 2, n2}, {1, 3, n3}, {2, 1, n4}, {2, 2, n5}, {2, 3, n6}};

array = SparseArray[{#, #2} -> #3 & @@@ data];

array // MatrixForm
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The function `Normal` can be used to convert the `SparseArray` into a regular list-of-lists array as needed:

```
Normal @ array
```

> ```
> {{n1, n2, n3}, {n4, n5, n6}}
> ```

Also [there is a StackExchange site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com) dedicated to *Mathematica* that I encourage you to explore.